# How to allow initializing a class from a particular class in ruby and nowhere else?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module

```
module A
  module B
    class Foo
      def initialize(args)
        @args = args
      end
      def call
        puts 'Inside Foo'
      end
    end
  end
end

module C
  class Boo
    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end
    def call
      puts 'Inside Boo'
      A::B::Foo.new(@args).call
    end
  end
end

boo = C::Boo.new(nil).call
# Inside Boo
# Inside Foo

A::B::Foo.new(nil).call
# Inside Foo
```

How can I avoid `A::B::Foo.new(nil).call` ? 
It should be accessible only from `Boo` class.

If anybody wants to access `Foo` class they will be able to access it from `Boo`.
How can I achieve this ?

Searched Internet but could not find what should be call this concept ?

Comment: You could make `A::B::Foo.new` _private_ (and use `send` to call it from within `Boo`)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the first place?

Comment: We have set of validation in ```class Boo```,
Which I cannot add in ```class Foo```.  
So, I don't want anyone to use ```class Boo``` without those validations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ruby - so there's no such thing as an iron-clad way of making an object "private". (For example, you can access private methods via `.send`!) But you can at least define a private *interface*.

However, your interface doesn't actually make much sense from an OOP perspective. Why is `A::B::Foo` accessible only within `C::Boo`? **If `A::B::Foo` is private, then it should only be accessible within `A::B`**, and nowhere else.

The key method you're looking for is: [`private_constant`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private_constant)

And you can circumvent a private constant lookup exception by using [`const_get`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/const_get).

Therefore we can "hack" your current implementation to work as follows:

```
module A
  module B
    class Foo
      def initialize(args)
        @args = args
      end
      def call
        puts 'Inside Foo'
      end
    end
    private_constant :Foo
  end
end


module C
  class Boo
    def initialize(args)
      @args = args
    end
    def call
      puts 'Inside Boo'
      A::B.const_get(:Foo).new(@args).call
    end
  end
end

# This works:
C::Boo.new(nil).call

# This errors:
A::B::Foo.new(nil).call
```

Comment: Likewise, you could achieve the above by making `A::B::new` a private method. But instead I suggest using `private_constant` because it appears that actually it's fine to initialise these object within certain contexts... I just don't think it makes much architectural sense to say "you can only initialise them within `C`"!

Comment: *`A::B::Foo::new`

Comment: It makes sense from a perspective where you consider C a Factory, and you don't want other classes to be able to create A::B unless they use C's interface. This is used in languages such as C# and Java with the "internal" keyword for example. (funny story, I had asked this a while ago since I come from a C# background and my question was flagged as a duplicate. People completely missed the point)

Comment: @cesartalves Ahh, I've not heard of this before... There's an [`InternalVisiblesTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) method in C#, interesting! This is also very similar to the "friend class" feature in C++.

Comment: Ruby doesn't really have the concept of "friend classes". I did find [this gem](https://github.com/lsegal/friend) that adds the functionality, though I haven't tried it!

Comment: If you wanted to dictate a factory-like interface for constructing an object, then I'd say that the "ruby way" would be to define `A::B::Foo.build` and make `A::B::Foo#new` private.

Comment: Hey, this gem is pretty great! Might have some use for it in the future :)